# I am new to WebRTC. I need to know if i require username and password to use WebRTC just like skype

Tags: javascript

I read article about WebRTC. I understood that it creates a common platform for real time communication. Can some one answer me that if WebRTC requires credentials and also is there any time limit to use.

Comment: You need to read more about WebRTC. It's a technology, not a commercial offering like Skype...

Comment: WebRTC is just a protocol.  You can build whatever you want with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a platform. According to webrtc.org, WebRTC is a free, open project that enables web browsers with Real-Time Communications (RTC) **capabilities** via simple JavaScript APIs.
If you want to develop it just with browser and your js code. http://www.webrtc.org/ has all the information you may want.

Comment: Is there any limitation for WebRTC. I mean the no:of video calls that we can make, time limits for each call,amount(bytes) of data that we can transfer.

Comment: I have no idea about this. Webrtc establishs a p2p connection between 2 browsers. After testing, the performance between two at the same place is excellent. And as far as I know, if lack of bandwidth, less frame will be transported.